# How MIMEs are detected

Tags: lubuntu, files, mime-type

I've searched around but can't seem to find any information on the topic.

How do you set the MIME type for an existing file?

For example, I'm trying to create a file with type `text/html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MIME types are not actually stored on the filesystem. They are merely a convenient way of knowing how to process a file. To get the MIME type, you have to run a program.

Some programs will detect the mime type of a file solely by looking at the file extension, while others will check the file for a **magic number** or a special **magic pattern**(essentially a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)).

---

As an example, run `touch test.html`, which creates an empty file.

Then run `xdg-mime query filetype test.html` or `mimetype test.html`. Both of them will return the type `text/html`.

However, if you run `file --mime-type -b test.html`, it will return `inode/x-empty`.

---

So, if you want all programs to act the same way on your file, the file should have the proper format (data) along with the correct extension.

> **What is a magic number?**
>
> Running `xxd image | head -1` on my profile image creates an output as
>   follows:
>
> `00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR`
>
> According to
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files),
>   `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` is the standard header for all `image/png`
>   files.

**How does the file command work?**

From the [`file(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) man page:

> There are three sets of tests, performed in this order: filesystem tests, magic tests, and language tests.
>   ...
>
> The filesystem tests are based on examining the return from a [`stat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call. The program checks to see if the file is empty, or if it's some sort of special file.
>   ...
>
> The magic tests are used to check for files with data in particular fixed formats.
>   ...
>   These files have a 'magic number' stored in a particular place near the beginning of the file that tells the UNIX operating system that the file is a binary executable, and which of several types thereof.
>   ...
>   If a file does not match any of the entries in the magic file, it is examined to see if it seems to be a text file.
>   ...
>
> Any file that cannot be identified as having been written in any of the character sets listed...is simply said to be 'data'.

**How does file know what magic patterns to use?**

Again, from the [`file(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) man page:

> The information identifying these files is read from the compiled magic file `/usr/share/misc/magic.mgc`, or the files in the directory `/usr/share/misc/magic` if the compiled file does not exist. In addition, if `$HOME/.magic.mgc` or `$HOME/.magic` exists, it will be used in preference to the system magic files. If /etc/magic exists, it will be used together with other magic files.

If I run `strace file image |& grep magic` we can see that `file` command looks for these files:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmagic.so.1  => [libmagic(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic)
>   ~/.magic.mgc
>   ~/.magic
>   /etc/magic.mgc
>   /etc/magic
>   /usr/share/misc/magic.mgc

There are other files like `/etc/mime.types` which other programs use. This file assigns an extension to a mime type. For example, `grep -i text/html /etc/mime.types` produces:

```
text/html                   html htm shtml
```

Comment: OK, but how exactly does that mechanism work? Does the kernel have built-in functionality for parsing the file when accessed and coming up with a type on the fly?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for updating. Thing is, HTML doesn't really have a "magic number". How does it get determined from XML or SGML? If I change the filename to "thing.c", it shows up as a c file, but if I omit any extension, then it gets recognized as HTML again. Kinda confusing for me. FYI, I am running Lubuntu with PCManFM.

Comment: Experimented a little more, I think it's searching for an <html>, <?xml?>, or <?php?> tag. Is this functionality stored in the kernel, generated on the fly when a mime is needed, or stored in the filesystem and parsed when saved?

Comment: Updated again...

Comment: The impression I'm getting is that libmagic subscribes to inode/filesystem events and processes the file when any change is made, updating he mime type. Is that correct? If not, how does libmagic get notified to reparse?

Comment: @Anonymous whatever program you're using to look at the file is what determines how it sees the file.  There is nothing in the OS or the filesystem that determines this.  When you write "it's searching for" what is "it"?

Comment: So there is no actual mime type stored in the filesystem, correct?

Comment: I wish I could upvote your post, but I can't.

Comment: I add an example too, hope it helps ;)

Comment: I'll start adding edits for your answer for future readers. I already knew how magic numbers worked, just not how the mime type would intelligently 'magically' change depending on the content. [This page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) and [this one](https://linux.die.net/man/5/magic) really helped.

Comment: **Thanks**! I finally understand this. Please approve my final edit to make it easier for future readers to understand.